# Is there any way to use Å letter in R?

Tags: r, encoding, letter

Is there any way to deal with this letter in R -Å?

In some configuration I'm able to read this letter from SQL by RODBC, but I didn't found any solution to save this letter to csv or txt. It's always getting converted to normal A or Ĺ.

Also, how to read this letter correctly from Excel file?

Comment: I just tried with `data.table::fwrite()` and it worked fine.

Comment: Can you read this letter from excel file?

Comment: I tried with `readxl::read_excel()` and it worked fine as well.

Comment: Something must be different, because I cannot read or write this letter as you.

Answer (score 0):

I understand from you question that the letter displays properly inside R but you have problems writing it to files.

R's writing functions usually have an encoding parameter (for example, for `write.csv` and `write.table` it's called `fileEncoding`).
When you don't set it explicitly, the function will encode the file using your OS's (or R-installations) native encoding, which can sometimes cause problems with special characters. What exactly goes wrong and how to fix it depends heavily on your system setup - especially if you're also interacting with databases, as you describe.

But very often, an easy fix is writing files in UTF-8 encoding, i.e.

`write.csv(your_df, your_path, fileEncoding='UTF-8')`

as most external programs (such as Excel) are able to automatically detect and properly read UTF-8 encoded files.

Comment: For some reason in the output file i have normal A letter.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the program you use to open the csv file rather than the csv file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `fileEncoding` argument on `write.table` to fit your needs (e.g., if your text is encoded as UTF-8, try `write.table(my_tab, file = "my_tab.txt", fileEncoding = "UTF8")`).

Comment: For some reason in the output file i have normal A letter.